# how to find Jack miss exam or enter exam?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Using the primitive statements of the following arguments and show them in symbolic form. Then establish the validity of the argument.

İf Jack can fall asleep or he is missing the bus, he won’t be able to take the exam on time. If Jack’s friend wakes him up, Jack can wake up. Jack’s friend wakes him up and Jack catches the bus on time. Therefore, Jack takes the exam on time.

My solution:

p:fall asleep

q:missing bus

k:jack's friend wake him up

t:enter the exam

$$(P \lor \lnot Q)\implies \lnot T$$

$$ K \implies (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$$

$$ T$$

Comment: So what the question is? :-) After all, "t".

Comment: @user12986714 added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like:
1. If Jack can fall asleep or he is missing the bus, he won’t be able to take the exam on time.
$$(P \lor Q) \implies \lnot T$$

2. If Jack’s friend wakes him up, Jack can wake up.
   $$K \implies \lnot P$$
3. Jack’s friend wakes him up and Jack catches the bus on time.
   $$K \land \lnot Q$$
4. Therefore, Jack takes the exam on time.
   $$\vdash T$$

The argument is **invalid** because statement 1 is not a double arrow. Missing the bus or falling asleep guarantees Jack missing the exam, but not missing the bus and not falling asleep does not mean Jack will absolutely not miss the exam (e.g. He had a medical emergency).

Comment: thanks friends.